# I want to copy a file's name into the document using bash

Tags: bash

I'm fairly new to using bash.

I have several hundred documents, each named QP1172, QP1474, QP9926, etc.  I need the name of the file to be in the first row of the document (so QP1172 for example would be in row 1 of the document QP1172.txt).

Does anyone know how I could do this?  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like

```
for f in QP????.txt; do echo $f | cat - $f >$f.withname; done
```

to create new files `QP1172.txt.withname` etc., and then replace the old ones with them after checking that everything looks ok.

(`cat` here concatenates the name (given on standard input) with the file contents of each file.)

ADDED: To make it easier to let the new versions get the right name afterwards it might be easier to let them have the same name, but in another directory.

```
mkdir withname
for f in QP????.txt; do echo $f | cat - $f >withname/$f; done
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `sed` to insert a line at the beginning:

```
for f in QP*; do
    sed -i "1i$f" "$f"
done
```

`1i$f` means "insert a line containing the value of `$f` before line 1".